# What is the difference between persist and set in redis?

Tags: redis

In Redis, I can set a key with expire time like

```
set key value ex 100
```

If I want to remove the expire time, I can do like

```
set key value
```

**OR**

```
persist key
```

What is the difference between this two?

Answer (score 2):

`PERSIST key` removes the expiration without the need to re-specify the value.

`SET key value` sets a new value. The expiration is removed as a side-effect.

Comment: You can get the details of these commands at https://redis.io/commands/persist/ and https://redis.io/commands/set/.

Answer (score 0):

Those two commands have same results on a key in terms of removing the expiry of any key, but the commands themselves are very different.

In Redis, any key which is overwritten - it's expiry logic is removed. When we run `SET key1 value1` - because the value of key `key1` is overwritten, that is why it's expiry is removed. (Note: Commands like `APPEND`, `SETRANGE` do not remove the expiry because they don't overwrite the key)

But what if you want to remove the expiry of the key without overwriting it? That's when you use `PERSIST`. It removes the expiry and makes the key permanent in the DB.